# azure function apps coding with java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I want to create a java function in azure but when I chose 'JAVA' as language in function apps, they only give 3 languages for scripts to create a function (c#, javaScript, F#). How can I code this in java and not javascript?

Answer (score 4):

Azure Functions support for Java is **currently in preview**. Find below detailed documentation on how to build Azure Functions in Java:

a)  Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven;

b) Developer Guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java;